# How to manage multiple ports exposed on port 80 with docker?

Tags: docker-compose, port, traefik

I have the following setup:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command:
      - --api.debug=true
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`monitor.domain.org`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web
    networks:
      - web
  db:
    image: registry.domain.com/repo/db:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
  api:
    image: registry.domain.com/repo/api:latest
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - 80:3001
    volumes:
      - /root/rsa.pem:/root/certs/rsa.pem
      - /root/rsa_pub.pem:/root/certs/rsa_pub.pem
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - MAIL_ADDRESS=${MAIL_ADDRESS}
      - MAIL_PASSWORD=${MAIL_PASSWORD}
      - MAIL_HOST=${MAIL_HOST}
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`api.domain.org`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web
    networks:
      - internal
      - web
  app:
    image: registry.domain.com/repo/app:latest
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
      - db
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`domain.org`,`www.domain.org`)
      - traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=web
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

Obviously I get an error from docker saying `Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated`. Either exposing the `port 80` of the `traefik` service or the `api` service separately works perfectly. If I do not expose the `port 80` on those both services it does not work for both of them. The `app` service which runs on Nginx works without exposing `port 80` seamlessly. How can I make the `api` and `traefik` service both run together on `port 80`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically you need to do for the api the same thing you did for the app, expose it via traefik.

In general what you usually want is to expose all your cluster internal services via traefik (or any other reverse proxy) for this reason only traefik is the one who should be exposed to host's ports. All your other services will just registered to at least one `entrypoint` of traefik in order to get requests.

So you just need to remove the `ports: - 80:3001` from your api service.

What will happen is that traefik only will listen to port 80 and all the traefik which has an http host header of `domain.org` or`www.domain.org` will be routed to app service though all requests with `api.domain.org` will be routed to your api service.

If you have done the above and you cannot send requests to your api service please share some logs from your service to check the errors most of the cases some headers need to be propagated to backend services in order for them to work properly.

PS. You are using the latest v2.0 version of traefik where apparently the registration of a service to an entrypoint is enough for traefik to route requests to this service. In previous versions you should add the label `traefik.port` to the service in order to advertise where your service is listening which was a bit more explicit to what was happening. [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/docker/#labels-overriding-default-behavior).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. You are right I did not need the ports in my compose file. Also Traefik had problems handeling two different networks at the same time :P